# How do I load my local json into List<Map> variable?

Tags: json, dart, flutter

How do I load my local json into List< Map > variable?

**This my local json.**

```
[
  {“id”: 00”, “name”: ”TRL”},
  {“id”: 01”, “name”: ”USD”},
  {“id”: 02”, “name”: ”GBP”},
  {“id”: 03”, “name”: ”EUR”},
]
```

**However this works:**

```
List<Map> _myCurrency = [
  {“id”: 00”, “name”: ”TRL”},
  {“id”: 01”, “name”: ”USD”},
  {“id”: 02”, “name”: ”GBP”},
  {“id”: 03”, “name”: ”EUR”},
];
```

My problem is I move my currency data into currency.json file. I can load the json but I cannot assign to List< Map > variable. Any help please?

**UPDATE:**

```
String jsonTCBanks =
await rootBundle.loadString("packages/capi/currency.json");
List<Map> _myCurrency = json.decode(jsonTCBanks);
```

**I get error as;**

> ```
> type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'
> ```

If I use Map _myCurrency the json.decode works, but I loose the key, value properties.

**UPDATE-2:**
I am keep getting error as:

```
I/flutter (16273): The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#44865):
I/flutter (16273): type 'MappedListIterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>, DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type
I/flutter (16273): 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'
```

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      String _mySelectedCurrency;
      List<Map> _myCurrencies;

      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        _loadLocalJsonData();
      }

      Future _loadLocalJsonData() async {
        String jsonCurrency = await rootBundle
            .loadString("packages/capi/currency.json");
        setState(() {
          _myCurrencies = List<Map>.from(jsonDecode(jsonCurrency) as List);
          print("*******_myCurrencies: $_myCurrencies");// This part works correctly
        }); 
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return _myCurrencies == null ? _buildWait(context) : _buildRun(context);
      }

  // TODO: BUILD RUN
  Widget _buildRun(BuildContext context) {
    final _itemsName = _myCurrencies.map((c) {
      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: c["id"].toString(),
        child: new Text(c["name"].toString()),
      );
    }).toList();

    return new Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: new SafeArea(
            top: false,
            bottom: false,
            child: new Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: new ListView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 32.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //TODO: CURRENCY ###########################################
                    new FormField<String>(
                      builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                        return InputDecorator(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'CHOOSE CURRENCY',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.green.shade700),
                            errorText: state.hasError ? state.errorText : null,
                          ),
                          isEmpty: _mySelectedCurrency == '',
                          child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                            child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                              value: _mySelectedCurrency,
                              isDense: true,
                              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _mySelectedCurrency = newValue;
                                  state.didChange(newValue);
                                });
                              },
                              items: _itemsName,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      validator: (val) {
                        return val != '' ? null : 'Choose Currency...';
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ))));
  }

      // TODO: BUILD WAIT
      Widget _buildWait(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        );
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode it from a string to a data structure and adjust the type by creating a new list with the desired type where you pass the list returned from `jsonDecode`:

```
import 'dart:convert';

...

List<Map> _myCurrency = List<Map>.from(jsonDecode(json) as List);
```

```
final currencyItems = _myCurrency.map(
    (c) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(c['id'], child: Text(c['name'])).toList();
DropdownButton(items: currencyItems);
```

Comment: I update my question. I get error as: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Comment: Thanks Günter its working. One last question. How do I add List<Map> _myCurrency  into dropdown button?

Comment: I will try thanks, if not works I will open new question

Comment: didn't worked as I keep getting same error. I update my question.

Comment: Chang `return new DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
        value: c["id"].toString(),` to `return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: c["id"].toString(),`

Comment: This time I get error on _myCurrencies.map((c){ part. Error:  The method 'map' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(Closure: (Map<dynamic, dynamic>)   DropdownMenuItem<String>) I update whole code

Comment: You need to check if `_myCurrencies` is `null`. Futures do not complete immediately (that's rather the point of them) and `_myCurrencies` only will have a value when the Future completed. When `build()` is called while `_myCurrencies` is `null`, you need to do something else (return an empty `Container()`, or create a dropdown without any entries, .... Also you need to call `setState` so that `build()` is executed again when the Future completes `setState(() =>_myCurrencies =  List<Map>.from(jsonDecode(jsonCurrency) as List));
`

Comment: Thanks, I update my code. And this time I get this error: type 'MappedListIterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>, DropdownMenuItem<String>>' is not a subtype of type.  'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>' Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.

Comment: You are missing the `.toList()` at the end of `.map()...`

Comment: Thank you very much, its working perfectly except I get overflow issue right side of  dropdown. And seems this is an issue. Am I right?

Comment: Overflow won't be visible in release builds like it is in debug builds, but it's a good idea to fix this anyway. But for that you should create a new question.